# Using the future tense in a sentence containing a dependent clause starting with "when"

Tags: tense, usage, future-tense

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> When we know what she decides, we will see what to do.

> When we will know what she decides, we see what to do.

> When we will know what she decides, we will see what to do.

The reason I am asking is that in Italian I would use the future tense for both the clauses, and I would tend to do the same in English too.

Comment: To better describe the situation in general you could say "When we find out what she decides, we will understand what to do."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER:
Only your first sentence is idiomatic English.

---

LONG ANSWER:
First, *will* is employed in *when* clauses only if *when* is employed as a relative adverb, not if *when* is employed as a subordinating conjunction:

> You will arrive in Milan at 4 pm, when you will be met by our representative.
>   <sup>✲</sup>When you will arrive in Milan you will be met by our representative.

Second, the ‘sequence of tenses’ rules for sentences with *[when] ... [then]* and *[if] ...[then]* constructions are very similar, so I’ll treat them together.

> NOTES: *I bracket* [when], [if] *and* [then] *because these words may only be implied and not actually appear in a sentence. Also, I have changed the words in your example to permit what I hope is a more transparent explanation.*

The rules vary depending on whether the sentence expresses habitual practice or, as in your example, a single contingency.

1. If the sentence expresses a repeated or habitual practice, both clauses will have the same tense: either simple present or simple past. In these cases, *[when]* or *[if]* bears the sense *whenever*.

   > [Our practice **is**: ] Whenever we **see** this, we **do** that.
   >   [Our practice **was**:] We **did** that whenever we **saw** this.
2. When the sentence deals with a single occasion, English employs a sequential structure, in which the *[then]* clause is depicted as ‘following’ the *[when]* or *[if]* clause. In practice this means that

   - In sentences with present reference, a simple present or present perfect in the *[when/if]* clause is paired with a *will* + *unmarked infinitive* construction in the *[then]* clause.

     > NOTE: 1) *The order of the clauses in the sentence is irrelevant, and* 2) *I speak of a ‘construction with* will’ *rather than of a ‘future tense’ because the* will *signifies consequence quite as much as it does futurity.*
     >
     > [We **have** decided:] If we **see** this, we **will do** that.
     >   [We **have** decided:] We **will do** that when we **have seen** this.
   - Sentences with past reference are ‘backshifted’: a simple past or past perfect in the *[when/if]* clause is paired with a *would* + *unmarked infinitive* construction in the *[then]* clause.

     > [We decid**ed** yesterday:] If we **saw** this, we **would do** that.
     >   [We decid**ed** yesterday:] We **would do** that when we **had seen** this.

Answer (score 5):

To decide which sentence is correct, put them in normal word order, which means "Begin the sentence with the independent clause instead of the dependent clause":

> We will see what to do when we know what she decides.
>   We see what to do when we will know what she decides.
>   We will see what to do when we will know what she decides.

It seems clear to me that only the first comes close to being idiomatic English. I'd revise it to read thus:

> We {will / shall} see what to do {when / after} we know what she has decided.

Italian and English apparently don't use the same sentence structure rules. The sequence of tenses is different in these languages.

Answer (score 0):

Time words including *when* as well as many others cannot be used with *will*; therefore, it is correct to say:

> When we know what she decides, we will see what to do.

To make it more formal, you could say:

> When/once she has decided, we will see what to do.