# What to use after "to think"

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

I have to translate a sentence and I'm checking some options. Can you tell me which one is correct?

The contest is more or less this one: "If I wear this t-shirt..."

- Do you think it will suite me?
- Do you think **that** it will suite me?
- Do you think (**that**) it is going to suite me?
- Do you think (**that**) it suits me?
- ...something different...

Any other suggestion/correction will be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb you're looking for is *suit*. *Suite* is a noun (pronounced like *sweet*), meaning a temporally, spatially or visually ordered composition of related but diverse elements: a suite of dances, a suite of rooms, a suite of furniture.

If you employ the *if* clause ("if I wear this T-shirt") you need a main clause with a futurive verb (*will* or *is going to*), for reasons explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/4494/32). Without the *if* clause ("Do you think this T-shirt [???] me?) you may use either a futurive or the simple present *suits*.

In any of these, the *that* is optional, and would probably be omitted in conversation.

Answer (score 2):

All of your listed items work. Using the future tense usually implies that you are not physically wearing the article of clothing, but perhaps, picking it out from an aisle of clothes and asking for feedback.

You could also say

> Do you think it suits me ?

This asks in the present tense, where you would be wearing the article of clothing and would be asking for immediate feedback. It is the same as saying *Do you think that it suits me?*