# "When I grow up, I am going to be a doctor"- Is it correct?

Tags: future-tense, will-vs-going-to

> When I grow up, I am going to be a doctor.

Is this sentence correct? Personally I think my growing up will happen in future and "I am going to be a doctor" sounds like it is going to happen in next month! But the sentence clearly indicates the speaker is a child. So according to me, "I am going to be a doctor" should be replaced by "I will be a doctor". So I think a more clear sentence would be

> When I will grow up, I will be a doctor.

Is my concept correct here?

Comment: I think you may be confusing *I am going to* with *I am about to*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think your concept is correct. The sentence is correct as written.  There is no different "distance into the future" implied by the use of *going to be* versus *will be*.  I can use either to talk about things that will happen in the next 2 minutes and the next billion years:

> I am going to finish this answer before I go to bed.
>   The Milky Way and the Andromeda galaxies are going to collide in about 4 billion years.

*Going to* may imply more of a *"on a path, trajectory or plan to achieve something"* whereas *will* just indicates futurity.

Comment: "Will" can refer to a dream here. *When I grow up, I will be a doctor.* - may mean that the person wants to become a doctor it doesn't mean that he finally will. *When I grow up, I am going to be a doctor.* sounds like he is sure of him becoming one.

Answer (score 8):

"When I will grow up, I will be a doctor." should be written as "When I grow up, I will be a doctor." to be idiomatic English. (See [Using the future tense in a sentence containing a dependent clause starting with "when"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/using-the-future-tense-in-a-dependent-clause-starting-with-when)​.)

"Be going to" is used to show what somebody intends to do in the future, but that doesn't necessarily means between five minutes.

> We are going to buy a house when we have saved enough money.

It is also used to show that something is likely to happen very soon or in the future.

> I think I am going to faint.

*Will* is used to speak about future or predicting the future (among other uses).

> By next year all the money will have been spent.

Comment: *Idiomatic* means "natural to a native speaker". Children where I grew up will invariably say "When I grow up, I am going to be a doctor" instead of "When I grow up, I will be a doctor." That seems to be true even if you phrase the question "What do you want to be when you grow up?" (Verified by asking my daughter.)

Comment: I was not referring to the fact the OP is using "I am going to" instead of "I will"; I was referring to the fact the OP wrote "When I will grow up, I will be a doctor."