# I am never going to talk to you ever again vs will never talk to you

Tags: future-tense, will-vs-going-to

What is the difference between "I am never going to talk to you ever again and "I will never talk to you ever again"

As far as I know, Present Continuous is used to talk about planned or scheduled events or events taking place in near future, but can we use it in this sentence for example. Or is only use of simple future valid?

Comment: It seems to me all that ***ever/never*** stuff is syntactically irrelevant, and that you're only really asking about the difference between ***I will do it*** and ***I am going to do it***.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["When I grow up, I am going to be a doctor"- Is it correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6335/when-i-grow-up-i-am-going-to-be-a-doctor-is-it-correct)

Answer (score 1):

"I'm never going to talk to you again" is perfectly normal.

"Planned or scheduled" is too narrow: the "gonna" form also expresses intention.

(I think it's unhelpful to talk about this as "present continuous". The present continuous of "talk" is "is/am/are talking". This construction uses the invariable "going to" (often pronounced, and sometimes written "gonna"), which might be analysed as some kind of auxiliary verb or even an adjective).