# Going to vs will

Tags: will-vs-going-to

What is the difference between I’m going to be late and I will be late?

I didn’t really understand the difference

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In depth explanation of the difference between "will" and "going to"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39850/in-depth-explanation-of-the-difference-between-will-and-going-to)

Comment: Also [“When I grow up, I am going to be a doctor”- Is it correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6335/9161)